# Change Detection: Difference between 'myObservable' and 'myObservable$ | async'

Tags: angular

I'm experiencing a change detection issue that I can't really wrap my head around:

I'm visualizing multiple locations on a map (angular2-google-maps), which works. The displayed locations come from an Observable (locations combined with currently selected locations):

```
const locations$ = LocationService.locations;
const selectedLocations$ = new BehaviorSubject<Location[]>([]);

this.displayLocations$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  locations$,
  selectedLocations$,
  (locations, selected) => locations.map(loc => {
    if (selected.indexOf(loc) !== -1) {
      return Object.assign({}, loc, {selected: true});
    } else {
      return loc;
    }
  })
)
```

When I emit a set of selected locations by invoking

```
selectedLocations$.next([setOfLocations]);
```

the view's updated just fine using (neither pre nor the map update)

```
this.displayLocations$.subscribe(l => this.displayLocations = l);

<pre>{{displayLocations | json}}</pre>
```

but here it's not: (both pre and the map update)

```
<pre>{{displayLocations$ | async | json}}</pre>
```

Until now I thought, both were equivalent change-detection-wise.

This is what I can say so far:

- adding `.do(console.log)` indicates that the resulting set is emitted just fine.
- This is not related to the maps module.
- All events come from within angular's zone, so (to me) this does not seem to cause the issue.
- The emitted arrays are different instances, adding `distinctUntilChanged()` does not discard them. Also adding `.map(arr => [...arr])` did not change anything.
- adding `.do(() => _cdr.markForCheck())` didn't have any effect on this.

Any hints on why and when `{{array}}` (with subscription in the controller) and `{{array$ | async}}` behave differently would be greatly appreciated, I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Can you create a plunker to demonstrate it?

Comment: Please check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/TgcQ8n0cfmxJrcjQXCz2?p=preview What is wrong there?

Comment: When you say the view isn't updated with the `displayLocations$ | async` syntax, you mean the `<pre>`'s content is not updated or the actual map?

Comment: neither is updated. I made a plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/BqYS7DMFvMfopGTVTCYO?p=preview. Too bad that it works in the plunk. Maybe I distilled my code too far. I'll try to reproduce the problem on plunker when I'm back from lunch.

Comment: Sorry for not coming back here! I wasn't able to reproduce my problem in a plunk. I ended up trashing the whole component and rewriting everything from scratch. Works now. Thanks for having a look!